# Cannot rename Windows partition on dual-boot machine

Tags: partitioning, windows, disk

I recently migrated from Win10 to Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop. For some reason, my [Windows partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCiDj.png) wasn't named 'Windows' in Nautilus after installing, as was the case with my laptop.

So, I unmounted the partition and attempted to fix this. Despite multiple Windows 10 shutdowns and booting back into Ubuntu, I keep getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSa20.png).

As far as I can tell, fast startup is disabled on Windows *(Power Settings > choose what the power buttons do > make additional options available)*. "Hibernate" wasn't in the list.

I'd be very grateful for any help in identifying the cause of this.

Comment: See what `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2` does.

Comment: @Zacharee1 http://imgur.com/4YZEqym

Comment: Now see if you can rename the partition.

Comment: @Zacharee1 nope, still throwing the same error.

Comment: Oh, hang on. When you boot into Windows, are you cancelling a chkdsk?

Comment: @Zacharee1 No idea what that is (other than some sort of command, I assume), so I'm going to guess not, lol.

Comment: Windows will boot to a screen saying something like "Windows needs to check one of your disks for integrity."

Comment: @Zacharee1 Haven't seen anything like that when booting into Windows, no. Just a normal boot-up.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try what the message suggested: boot into Windows twice and try again?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yep, no dice on that either. To be honest, this machine has been giving me nothing but trouble since I started this whole process by installing last night. Think I'm just going to boot into Windows, delete the Ubuntu partition + GRUB, and try again from my Live USB. There have been about a million different things that haven't been working right on this desktop that were fine on the laptop. It's getting frustrating, lol. Appreciate your help anyway, I'll let you know how it goes after the reinstall.

Comment: That would be something to try :)

Comment: @Zacharee1 Boom! It worked. Whatever it was before, a complete un-and-reinstall fixed it.

Comment: People tend to just blow over comments and not read them. I'd recommend either posting it as an answer or editing it into your question and letting us close it.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally got it working. I'm not sure what it was, but a complete un-and-reinstall fixed it.

**Note: I'd recommend trying to repair your Ubuntu installation before going through all of this, which can be done by running from a Live USB without having to delete the Ubuntu partitions or GRUB. It's a much simpler process. I'm only posting all this because I tried that first and it didn't work.**

Steps I took:

- Boot into Windows.
- Delete Ubuntu's partitions (type 'partition' in the search and it should come up; make sure you only delete ones that Windows says it
  didn't create/doesn't recognize).
- Create a Windows recovery drive (again, type 'recovery' into the search and there should be an option that says "create a recovery
  drive). I used a USB thumbdrive for this step.
- Reboot your computer, and spam the key your motherboard uses to start setup (in my case, this was `Del`,
  but it could also be `Esc` or one of the function keys.). This part may require some trial and error, but it shouldn't
  be too hard to figure out after a couple restarts.
- Once in your BIOS/UEFI, change the boot order to have USB drives at the top. There should be an abundance of videos on YouTube to help
  with this, but just in case, here's a [helpful article](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/).
- Save and exit the BIOS/UEFI (usually `F10`).
- Your computer should boot into the recovery environment stored on the USB you set up. I have Windows 10, but the process should be more
  or less the same for other versions: go to Troubleshoot > Advanced >
  Command Prompt, and enter `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`.
- After Step 7, both Ubuntu and GRUB (the screen that lets you choose between booting into Ubuntu or Windows) should both be gone.
  At this point, you can re-install Ubuntu from a Live USB, etc. as
  normal.

Source I used (in case my instructions are unclear):

[Uninstall Linux and GRUB from Windows 8 Dual-Boot](https://www.techmesto.com/uninstall-linux-grub-dual-boot-windows8/)

*Note: I did this on a Windows 10 dual-boot system, but the process is almost identical.*

After all this is completed and Ubuntu is set up again, simply search for "Disk" in the Dash, unmount the partition/drive you're trying to rename (click the "stop" square), then right-click and select "edit filesystem". Rename the drive and enter your password to authenticate.